# How to republish video with new opentok sdk

Tags: android, opentok

I use the latest `opentok` Android SDK to development an application. My purpose is to provide a button to let user can publish / unpublish camera. It works to unpublish the camera using `publisher.setPublishVideo(false);` , but it doesn't work to republish when I use `publisher.setPublishVideo(true);`.

And I also try to use `publisher.destroy()` to delete the publish and recreate the publisher and then publish it, however since `publisher.destroy` has been called, either publisher and subscriber's video all disappear. It's very weird.

Am I using the wrong way or could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I just reproduced this and it seems to be a bug in the OpenTok API.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok's Android SDK is still in beta so its has errors here and there. You have caught an error, and this error has been reported to OpenTok. Will update when this error has been resolved.

edit- This bug will be fixed in Android 1.0.1